# PostGIS minimum distance between two large sets of points

Tags: postgis

I have two tables of points in PostGIS, say A and B, and I want to know, for every point in A, what is the distance to the closest point in B. I am able to solve this for small sets of points with the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, MIN(ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, b.geom))
FROM table_a a, table_b b
GROUP BY a.id;
```

However, I have a couple million points in each table and this query runs indefinitely. Is there some more efficient way to approach this. I am open to getting an approximate distance rather than an exact one.

**Edit:** A slight modification to the answer provided by JGH to return distances in meters rather than degrees if points are unprojected.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, nn.id AS id_nn, 
    a.geom, nn.geom_closest, 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, nn.geom_closest) AS min_dist
FROM 
    table_a AS a
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        (SELECT
            b.id, 
            b.geom AS geom_closest
        FROM table_b b
        ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom
        LIMIT 1) AS nn;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is slow because it computes the distance between every points without using any index. You could rewrite it to use the [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator that uses the index if used in the `order by` clause.

```
select a.id,closest_pt.id, closest_pt.dist
from tablea a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT
     id , 
     a.geom <-> b.geom as dist
     FROM tableb b
     ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom
   LIMIT 1) AS closest_pt;
```