# Nearest Neighbour search in postgis giving wrong result

Tags: postgis, nearest-neighbor

I try to find the nearest station to a set of polygons. I use the following query but the result is always the same station (actually the one with the lowest id).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id) 
    a.id AS field_id,
    a.name,
    a.geom AS field_location,
    b.stations_id,
    b.stationsname,
    st_distance(a.geom, b.geom) AS dist
   FROM fields_filtered a,
    kl_stationsliste b
  WHERE b.bis_datum > '2020-04-01'::date
  ORDER BY a.id, b.stations_id, (st_distance(a.geom, b.geom));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551479 may be of interest to you

Comment: I think your st_distance needs to be the second argument in the order by statement.