# Searching nearest neighbour in same Table GIS Postgrsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We have a database of individual trees with geo location in the DB we seem to have a geom point combined from long and lat named estimated_geometric_location. We get a periodic update of these trees lets say every month. I would like to get a list of trees that has two properties. I am looking to identify the most likely update of a specific tree ie. when a new set of trees from one tracking event comes we need to run a routine suggesting date entry x.2 is an update of the datapoint x.1. Ideally this routine then updates the new data point(child) adding the older mother data point which then hopefully represents that same tree.

So far i have something like this but the DB is not responding (or maybe i am not waiting long enough... waited about 10minutes so far)

```
SELECT
     i.id
    ,ST_Distance(i.estimated_geometric_location, i.b_estimated_geometric_location) AS dist
FROM(
SELECT
     a.id
    ,b.id AS b_id
    ,a.estimated_geometric_location
    ,b.estimated_geometric_location AS b_estimated_geometric_location
    ,rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY ST_Distance(a.estimated_geometric_location, b.estimated_geometric_location)) AS pos
FROM trees a, trees b 
WHERE a.id <> b.id) i
WHERE pos = 1
```

Would be great to get some ideas on this. I got this from a post here somewhere and have adapted it but so far no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostGIS minimum distance between two large sets of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551479/postgis-minimum-distance-between-two-large-sets-of-points)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to mention. If the data comes from a tracking event, why compare existing trees to each other? I'd expect to have something like

```sql
SELECT id
FROM trees
ORDER BY st_distance(estimated_geometric_location, st_makepoint(15, 30))
LIMIT 1
```

which returns the tree closest to the point with longitude 15 and latitude 30. Have a look at whether you need to do that join at all.

---

Supposing that you do, the problem with a query like this is complexity. If you have any number (say 1000) trees in your database, then you're actually calculating the distances between 1000 trees and all of their 999 counterparts, calculating 999.000 distances! Just saying that if the distance between A and B is the same as between B and A, then you should be able to shave off half of them by saying `a.id < b.id`.

Furthermore, think about what you're doing. You want to find the minimal distance between any two trees and the ids of the trees that correspond to that distance, right? There is no need to calculate any distances as soon as you know they're not the minimal one.

```sql
SELECT a.id, b.id, ST_Distance(a.estimated_geometric_location, b.estimated_geometric_location)) distance
FROM trees a, trees b 
WHERE a.id < b.id
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
```

is a much simpler way of getting there, and for me it's a lot faster as well.